# Why does page exhibit "scroll memory"?

Tags: html

I've created a page where the body height is specified to be twice the height of the page content. If I load the page and scroll to the bottom, and then reload the page in the browser, the page comes in  and auto-scrolls to the bottom, where I left it. The browser seems to remember where it was and continues there the next time the page is loaded.

I don't want this behavior.  I want the page to always start with no scroll, so the top of the page is at the top of the viewport.

I've tried doing a $(document).scrollTop(0) but I suspect that the browser is doing its scroll down to the last position after this is executed.

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can keep the browser from scrolling down to the previou scroll position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a 'feature' in many browsers. You may try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        scrollTo(0,-1);
    },0);
}
</script>
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
            scrollTo(0,-1);
        },0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  The 0 timeout wasn't enough.  I had to set it up to 1500 to get after the browser did its scroll down.